# How to get the length of an object javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I would get the length of an object on js but I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I don't know either - what you even mean by that to begin with. Please go read [ask] first of all. And then edit your question to contain a proper example object, and what "length" you expect to get back for that.

Comment: Read about Object.keys. You can get the length of that array, if that's what you mean. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

var length = Object.keys(Obj).length;